# Bash: Replace all occurrences of a word in the last command

Tags: linux, command-line, bash

Almost by mistake, I figured out you could do something like:

```
$ cp foo.data bar1.data
$ ^bar1^bar2
```

And that runs the same command with `bar2.data` instead of `bar1.data`. Now, how about if I have multiple occurrences of the target word? For example:

```
$ cp foo.data bar.data
$ ^data^index
```

It only replaces the first `data` extension. How do I get it to replace both?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I think `^data^index` is equivalent to `!!:s/data/index`, so it will only substitute the first word.  If you want the whole line substituted, I think you'll have to use `!!:gs/data/index/`

Comment: This replacement (:gs/data/index) is a bash feature or is it implicitly calling another program?

Comment: [Is a bash feature](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#History-Interaction)

Answer (score 9):

You can do it by adding ^:& to the end.
^:& will replace two occurrences
^:g& will replace all

```
$ cp foo.data bar.data
$ ^data^index^:&
$ cp foo.index bar.index
```

```
$ cp foo.data bar.data joe.data doe.data
$ ^data^index^:g&
$ cp foo.index bar.index joe.index doe.index
```

*sidenote: in the book 'command line kungfu'
 it says that ^:& will replace all*

Comment: Actually, `^:&` will do the substitution *twice*.  To do ***all*** occurrences, use `^:g&` (`g` stands for "global").

Comment: Tnx ! I never tested it for more than two occurrences. Read the command in a book.